# Why are "context" dependencies so often passed implicitly in Scala?

Tags: scala, implicit

I'm curious why passing "context" dependencies is so often done implicitly in Scala. I'm looking at the fs2-kafka library, and as usual, deserializers are passed implicitly. I'm having a hard time seeing the advantages of this, it seems like it just obfuscates the code by hiding dependencies. Does anyone know what the upsides are of passing parameters in this way?

Edit: To be clear, I'm not asking whether this is a good practice; that's subjective. I'm wondering what the reasoning is. We wouldn't pass most dependencies implicitly just to avoid the inconvenience of having to pass them in explicitly, so why is it so often done with context dependencies like deserializers?

Comment: It probably simplifies the code a lot by not having to pass the same dependencies explicitly everywhere?

Comment: Akka uses this pattern, so it is common to akka related projects to do that. It is impossible to answer this objectively, it was a design decision. Many people see that as a simplification, others seems like a horrible bad practice.

Comment: Definitely -- whether it's a good practice is subjective. I was just wondering what the claimed upside was. Bergi's response is the only one I've heard and it seems like there must be a better reason; you don't normally hide your dependencies to avoid the inconvenience of having to pass them in, so I'm not sure why context parameters are treated differently. I'll clarify the question.

Answer (score 2):

Deserializers are usually typeclasses, and the way that Scala implements typeclasses is via `implict` arguments. Doing this manually is going to be a lot more code and require the programmer to do type matching that the compiler can do itself with a typeclass.

A better example of a simple dependency would be `ExecutionContext` in `scala.util.Future` methods, and in this case it simplifies the calling code and makes it easier to provide a different context within a given scope.